# Rails 4 - Render controller variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a Rails newbie and this seems like a trivial thing, but I can't figure out how to render this.

I have a form that takes in a string input:

```
<%= form_for @idea do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :idea_list %>
    <%= f.text_field :idea_list %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And a controller:

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @idea = Idea.new
  end

  def create
    @idea = Idea.new(idea_params)

    if @idea.save
      render :index
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def idea_params
    params.require(:idea).permit(:idea_list)
  end
end
```

I then want to render the `idea_list` parameter in `index.html.erb`, but cannot figure out how to do so. I've tried:

```
<p><%= @idea %></p>
```

but I get an output of `#<Idea:0x007f8b16d98638>`.

```
<% @idea do |idea| %>
  <p><%= idea.idea_list %></p>
<% end %>
```

I've tried many variations of this but keep getting various errors.

Please help.

Comment: Should just be `@idea.idea_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `@idea` is an instance of an object. `idea_list` is an attribute. So you need to call `@idea.idea_list`. Any time you want to reference an instance of an object  / model from a controller it's going to `@instance.attribute`.

In your case, it's going to be

```
<p><%= @idea.idea_list %></p>
```

If you want to show them from a list of the all, in your view it's

```
<%@ideas.each do |idea| %>
  <p><% idea.idea_list%></p>
<% end%>
```

And in your controller it's

```
def index 
  @ideas = Idea.all
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. I could have sworn I tried that.

Comment: Glad it helped. FYI, [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) are great for getting started with using Rails and as a reference.